# Formatting label symbol based on table values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I'm trying to modify the format of a label symbol in ArcMap. See the attached screenshot...
I would like the symbol to change color(orange) based on if there is a value in the Joint District field. I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear what you are referring to, that yellow circle or the other text labels you show on the screen?  If yellow circle you need to show what the current expression is.  Not enough info for people to answer.

Comment: Sorry. It's the yellow circle I'm trying to change. I would like it to be orange if it's a joint district.

Answer (score 1):

In the layer properties your method is set to "Label all the feature the same way", Change that to "Set classes and label each class differently". Create two class and szet an SQL query for each class based on your Joint District field (something like `"JointDistrict" IS NULL` for the first and `"JointDistrict" IS NOT NULL` for the second). You will now be able to to style each category separately.

If you want your label to be identical but for the background color define all symbology option before setting the method, as the newly created category will inherit the previous setting you will just need to change background color rather than doing it two time.